# reader return line space between every line when print the lines of textfile

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I want to retrieve the lines from text file like this:

```
line one
line two 
line three
```

but the output is like this :

```
line one
space line
line two
space line
line three
```

and this is my code:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/users/Moath Ibrahem/Desktop/Questions.txt"));
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are blank lines present in your file and since you are reading and printing everything, it is printing the blank lines as well.

If you want to avoid printing the blank lines then you can check for the blank line before printing it.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/users/Moath Ibrahem/Desktop/Questions.txt"));
        String str = br.readLine();
        if(!str.equals("")) {
            System.out.print(str);
        }
        /* Repeat */
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

```
line one
line two 
line three
```

Comment: i want output to be like this :
line one 
line two
if i use print output will be like this:
line onelinetwo

Comment: You should check if the line you are reading is empty or not. If it is empty then do not print it.

Comment: the data in the file like this:
line one
line two
without spaces!

Comment: @Moath Your Welcome!